# Как сделать загрузку шрифтов из Google fonts, даже если они есть локально?

Tags: html, css, шрифты, google-fonts

Использую *Roboto* на своем сайте, вся разработка шла из под *Mac OS* и в самом конце я столкнулся с проблемой:

Под *Windows 10*, на некоторых машинах, *Roboto* рендерится с характерными для его ранних версий ошибками (Щ как Ш при `font-weight=300`, кривая кавычка). Причина заключается в том, что на ПК установлена старая версия шрифта.

Но проблема возникающая на моем сайте, не характерна для для других сайтов, использующих *Roboto* - [например](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900).

Я подключаю шрифт так:

```
<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900&subset=cyrillic-ext');</style>
```

Наверное вопрос можно сформулировать так: как сделать приоритетным использование шрифтов из *Google fonts* над локально установленными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В css-файле, на который вы ссылаетесь, есть приоритет локальных шрифтов. Вы можете скачать этот файл, удалить все  `local('название гарнитуры'),` оставив только `url('Адрес шрифта на GF')`. Или поместите `local('название гарнитуры')` в конец строки.  Затем подключите этот файл вместо текущего.